# How to pass an object as a dependency within objective c init?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

This is my objc interface:

```
@interface MobileKeysController : NSObject <MobileKeysManagerDelegate>
- (id) initWithLogger:(Loggable *)logger; //issue: Expected a type
- (void) didPressRegistrationButton:(NSString *)code;
@end
```

I have also a private interface:

```
@interface MobileKeysController ()
@property(nonatomic) Loggable *logger;
@end
```

and custom init:

```
- (id)initWithLogger: (Loggable *) logger_ {
    self = [super init];
    // how can I assign it here from an init?
    return self;
}
```

This is my Swift definition:

```
protocol Loggable: class {
    func log(_ category: FirebaseCategory, _ type: FirebaseEventType, _ dataProvider: FirebaseEventDataProvider)
}

@objc class FirebaseLogger: NSObject, Loggable {
    // MARK: - Loggable
    func log(_ category: FirebaseCategory, _ type: FirebaseEventType, _ dataProvider: FirebaseEventDataProvider) {
        log(category.rawValue, type.value, dataProvider.parameters)
    }
}
```

And I need to use it from Swift file like this:

```
let logger = FirebaseLogger()
return MobileKeysController(logger: logger)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `id<Loggable>` instead of `Loggable *` and mark protocol with `@objc`